# Load infile with contents have backslash

Tags: mysql

I have problem when i do a load infile, where its contents have ip address within it,

in side the file

> [10] Mon 08Jul19 00:10:05 - (8457737) file `"D:\a\b\c\file.zip"`

After load infile the backslashes are removed

> [10] Mon 08Jul19 00:10:05 - (8457737) file `"D:abcfile.zip"`

but to no avail,

I am wondering how to combat this

thanks in advance

Searched through stackoverflow, dbjournal and forums

I have tried the following

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
ENCLOSED BY '' 
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

and

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Comment: Are you able to edit the file itself? The easiest solution would be to do a search and replace there to replace '\' with '\\'

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I am able to edit the file, but this will be an automated system and i would rather know if its possible to load, if not then i will have to add the feature of changing within the file before loading

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `FIELDS ESCAPED BY ''` to turn off escapes altogether. e.g.:

```sql
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
ENCLOSED BY '' 
ESCAPED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

What you had, `FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\\'` means to interpret backslashes in the input file as escape characters (to escape the following character).

So the input

> D:\a\b\c\file.zip

would be read as a 'D' followed by a colon followed by an escaped 'a' (which is just an a), an escaped 'b', and so on. If you had had a backslash followed by a 't', then it would have been read as a protected tab character. But there are no special characters associated with `\a`, so you just get 'a' in that case.

By using `FIELDS ESCAPED BY ''`, you're telling the file reader that there are no escape characters. With that set, then the backslash is just read (and retained) as a backslash.

If you needed backslashes and you also needed escapes for other special characters, you could pick a character of your choice to server as the escape character. Something that didn't show up very much in the input data itself (or it, too, would have to be escaped). I'd guess that usage would be pretty rare, though. One either needs escape characters and uses backslash as the escape character (escaping whatever backslashes are actually needed), or one just turned off the escape altogether.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion and it worked, thank you very much indeed, a little bit confused as i tried this before but with ESCAPED BY '\\', As it was suggested in some of my research, definitely need to read on this, again thank you

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, this is very helpful,